# Multiple match dataset "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Tags: r

```
Emails <- c("Bob@gmail.com","Mike@aol.com","Lyndsey@blue.com","Ethan@gmail.com","Sara@gmail.com",
           "Sarah@yahoo.com","Leo@stuff.com","Raj@blue.com")
State <- c("Washington","California","Texas","Iowa","New York","California","Alabama","Alaska")
PPP <- data.frame(Emails = Emails,State = State)

Emails <- c("Bob@gmail.com","Mike@aol.com","Lyndsey@blue.com","Ethan@gmail.com","Sara@gmail.com",
           "Sarah@yahoo.com","Leo@stuff.com","Raj@blue.com","Lyndsey@blue.com","Ethan@gmail.com","Sara@gmail.com",
           "Sarah@yahoo.com","Leo@stuff.com","Raj@blue.com","Mike@aol.com","Lyndsey@blue.com","Ethan@gmail.com","Sara@gmail.com",
           "Sarah@yahoo.com","Leo@stuff.com")
ProductPurchased <- c("Hat","Bat","Cat","Hat","Candy","Fruit","Candy","Cat","Hat","Candy","Fruit",
                      "Candy","Cat","Hat","Candy","Fruit","Candy","Cat","Hat","Candy")
Purchases <- data.frame(Emails = Emails,ProductPurchased = ProductPurchased)

Left <- merge(x = PPP, y = ProductPurchased, by.x = "Emails", by.y = "Emails", all.x = TRUE)
```

Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: ProductPurchased must be data.frame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to merge works if you change the y-input from ProductPurchased to Purchases.